# How to find a data warehouse's design diagram?

Tags: data-warehouse

I have a database with lots of tables. I need to quickly find out what data warehouse schema was used. Specifically, looking for the dimensions and fact tables. There does not seem to be a standard naming convention. The database diagram is not showing anything.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a product that can perform [database design reverse engineering](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=reverse+engineer+database+design&t=ffsb&atb=v65-7&ia=web).

Having said that, we refrain from giving product advice on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) since questions about which tool, library, product or resource you should use quickly become obsolete and often are just about the preferences of the answerer.

Answer (score 0):

If the diagram tool did not work for you, that likely means there are no foreign keys or constraints which will make things difficult for you. Max has already stated about third party tools, and you said there is no similar naming convention. To me, this leaves two pieces that are in SQL Server and neither are great and you'll have to do some manual work.

I've used this frequently and it helps me. I'm thinking that if the table names aren't consistent, hopefully the column names are consistent or close. If they aren't, hopefully your data types and sizes are.

```
SELECT t.NAME AS table_name
    ,SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) AS schema_name
    ,c.NAME AS column_name
    ,st.NAME 'Data type'
    ,c.max_length 'Max Length'
    ,c.precision
    ,c.scale
    ,c.is_nullable
    ,ISNULL(i.is_primary_key, 0) 'Primary Key'
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
INNER JOIN sys.types st ON c.user_type_id = st.user_type_id
LEFT JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = c.object_id
    AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
LEFT JOIN sys.indexes i ON ic.object_id = i.object_id
    AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
ORDER BY schema_name
    ,table_name;
```

You may have to adjust the `ORDER BY` section by `column_name` or `data type`, but it will help sort the metadata of the tables in your database and you can find things related or similar to each other.

Past that, this may not be a good idea for you, but just an idea I had.

As you find things in relation, you can change the names of the tables and then create synonyms for their past naming convention. Then when you can process change requests with your folks who need to access those table names, you can slowly remove the synonyms as they change their reference points.

At the very least, I'd recommend to start a data dictionary or you can possibly begin adding better naming to the extended properties of tables in the database.